# Pass data into JQuery then HTML (multi-step)

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, slidedown

I am trying to allow a global function to be called and pass text into an alert box, which is set at the top of the page.

My code is:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fadehelper').fadeIn('slow');

    function msg(data, type) {
      $('.warning').slideDown("slow").delay(1500).slideUp("slow");
    }
  });
</script>
```

And the message box is:

```
<div class="warning">Help me!</div>
```

I am not really sure how to do this..

I want to pass a type and a message. The class will be the type, and the message will do where the "Warning" goes.

So if I go somewhere in the page and go msg(warning, "help me!"); I want that to be translated like above.

Can you help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, put an id attribute on the div so that it can be found easily. I will assume you are using alertbox as the id in the following function

Add the following to the end of the msg function:

```
var box=document.getElementById('alertbox');
box.setAttribute('class',type);
box.innerHTML=data;
```

It can probably be done shorter in jquery but I don't use jquery

Comment: @Markassoftware Uncaught ReferenceError: type is not defined

Comment: You had type as an argument to msg. If you provided it as an argument, it would exist, so you mabye didn't have it as an argument. Try running this, and it should work: msg('hello','warning'); Also, in your little piece of code in msg that makes the element slide up and down, replace .warning with #alertbox One last thing: spell my username with one s

Answer (score 0):

```
function msg(type, data){
   var box=document.getElementById('alertbox');
    box.setAttribute('class',type);
    box.innerHTML=data;
    $('#alertbox').slideDown("slow").delay(1500).slideUp("slow");
}
```

Got it!

Comment: That is exactly what I answered